# is re.split("\W") = re.split("\w")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

As the title says, is `re.split("\W")` the same as `re.split("\w")` because the results I get are the same whichever I use. The same goes if it has `+` or not. Is this right? Or it works in some cases, and if yes why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: they are not the same, they are opposites. Show the input string to make the question more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not the same thing at all:

```
>>> test_string = 'hello world'
>>> import re
>>> re.split('\w', test_string)
['', '', '', '', '', ' ', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> re.split('\W', test_string)
['hello', 'world']
```

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) does the following:

> Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
>       returning a list containing the resulting substrings.

`\w` and `\W` are:

> ```
> \w       Matches any alphanumeric character; equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].
>          With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus characters defined
>          as letters for the current locale.
> \W       Matches the complement of \w.
> ```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `\W+` as it is more general. For example, if you have `'London, United Kingdom'`, it returns `['London', 'United', 'Kingdom']`. Without the `+`, it would have returned: `['London', '', 'United', 'Kingdom']` (notice the extra empty string).